# Identifying software and version range in a sentence

Tags: nlp, nltk

I have sentences similar to the following format

> This vulnerability happened in `Firefox` `1.x` before `1.8`, `Safari`
>   `2.x` before `2.8`.

Given the above sentence, I want to extract a dictionary

```
{Firefox: 1.0-1.8, Safari: 2.0-2.8}
```

Problem is how should I identify the version range with the software they belong to, using NLP techniques?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a combination of NERs, one for detection of names and one for versions:

[image]
[image]

You may have to: 
 - Keep a list of popular softwares in case NER misses it.
 - Hacky way to fix the software version numbers; like "1.x" is not properly detected.

You can play with it here: http://nlp.cogcomp.org

Comment: Thanks! Any idea of how to match the versions with software after detection?

Comment: I'd say just add some rules to fix the issue. No current software can detect such numbers...